# Kubectl networkpolicy doesnt work with MySQL

Tags: mysql, linux, kubernetes

This is actually my first time ever asking a question online so I hope I give all the information possible, if something is missing I will be sure to add it later!

I am running a kubernetes cluster which I installed with rancher - network plugin used is canal.
I will describe what I have and what I am trying to achieve. I have 2 pods, 1 is a mysql database and the other is a web pod that connects to the database and writes data from user input ( all is test environment ).

For this particular post that I am writing, I will not post YAML of the web page, instead, I am running a test pod mysql-client to test connection through there, since its the same as my web page image and it saves space on this post.

I want to limit the mysql pod to only accept inbound from the web pod.
I followed [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/declare-network-policy/) tutorial. First, I tried everything as they say with their examples and it all worked. When I made changes to suit my needs, it doesnt work.
I will now present you with my yamls.

MySQL deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "1"
  creationTimestamp: "2022-01-19T06:47:38Z"
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app: example
  name: example
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "1350559"
  uid: 38190642-9f8d-497b-8afb-c41284b734e2
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: example
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: example
        restrict: me
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: 172.23.0.5:5000/custom-mysql-db:v1
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: custom-mysql-db
        resources: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
status:
  availableReplicas: 1
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: "2022-01-19T06:47:41Z"
    lastUpdateTime: "2022-01-19T06:47:41Z"
    message: Deployment has minimum availability.
    reason: MinimumReplicasAvailable
    status: "True"
    type: Available
  - lastTransitionTime: "2022-01-19T06:47:38Z"
    lastUpdateTime: "2022-01-19T06:47:41Z"
    message: ReplicaSet "example-68588d446f" has successfully progressed.
    reason: NewReplicaSetAvailable
    status: "True"
    type: Progressing
  observedGeneration: 1
  readyReplicas: 1
  replicas: 1
  updatedReplicas: 1
```

MySQL Service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2022-01-19T06:47:44Z"
  labels:
    app: example
  name: example
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "1350571"
  uid: 264a957c-f7f4-4fa2-95b2-1839d0f0c00e
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.43.230.220
  clusterIPs:
  - 10.43.230.220
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - nodePort: 30619
    port: 3306
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 3306
  selector:
    app: example
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: NodePort
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

And now the network policy I use:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: access-nginx
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      restrict: me
  ingress:
  - from:
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          access: "true"
```

I am running a mysql-client with this command:
kubectl run clientms --rm -ti --labels="access=true" --image=mysql -- /bin/sh

and inside I am running this command:
mysql -h 172.23.0.11 -P 30619 --protocol=TCP -u root -p -v

Without the networkpolicy, everything connects fine and works(both my mysql-client test pod and my actual web page pod). But with the networkpolicy applied, I try to connect with the command above and it hangs and doesnt connect, but doesnt fail either.

I have tried replacing the address in the command with "example" as shown on my kubectl get svc output:

```
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
example      NodePort    10.43.230.220   <none>        3306:30619/TCP   33m
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.43.0.1       <none>        443/TCP          9d
```

I would like some help please understanding why it doesnt work any maybe even get a solution for this. thank you, if you need more information please comment, I will check this thread every few hours on my working times.
Good day :)

Comment: do you have any other network policies applied ? because i have tried similar on my test setup it worked fine. I think there might be some policies which blocking the access.

Comment: Hello friend, I do not have any more network-policies applied.
Usually when something blocks or refuses then the mysql client stops, in my case it just hangs.

Comment: @confusedgenius maybe you could guide me what exactly to check? and I will post the results.

Comment: to start with ``` kubectl get netpol -o wide -A``` . If there are any listed then kubectl describe of those policies.

Comment: @confusedgenius Hey. The only network policy that is listed is the one I attacked the yaml of.